# Importing classes just for typing in python?

Tags: python, python-import, python-typing

I am trying to use typing in Python 3.8 and I am a bit stuck.
Example: I am mainly developing in `main.py`. I also have a class `util.py` that contains some helper functions an classes. But these classes also need to import classes from `main.py` for Typing. Now, when I want to use functions from `util.py` in `main.py` I also need to import it - but then I'll get an error because of circular importing (and rightly so).

Is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Sylvio's answer is correct, but I want to address **just for typing** in your title.

*Importing classes **just for typing** in python?*

If the only reason you are importing a class is to address some typing consideration, you can use the [typing.TYPE_CHECKING](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484) constant to make that import conditional.

Quoting that documentation:

> Runtime or type checking?
>
> Sometimes there's code that must be seen by a type checker (or other static analysis tools) but should not be executed. For such situations the typing module defines a constant, **TYPE_CHECKING**, that is considered True during type checking (or other static analysis) but False at runtime. Example:

```
import typing

if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import expensive_mod

def a_func(arg: 'expensive_mod.SomeClass') -> None:
    a_var = arg  # type: expensive_mod.SomeClass
    ...
```

> (Note that the type annotation must be enclosed in quotes, making it a "forward reference", to hide the expensive_mod reference from the interpreter runtime. In the # type comment no quotes are needed.)

Bottom line is that you may very well not have to import it all, *except for when you are type-checking*.

Answer (score 5):

Circular imports are not an immediate error in Python; they're only an error if you use them in a particular way. I believe you're looking for [forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)

Example `main.py`:

```
import util

class SomeClass:
    pass
```

Example `util.py`

```
import main

# We can't use main.SomeClass in the type signature because of the cycle,
# but we can forward reference it, which the type system understands.
def make_some_class() -> "main.SomeClass":
    return main.SomeClass()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to prevent that is to move every class in their own file, and import them where you need them.
Declaring multiple class in a single file is not good for code maintenance and can make big application harder to debug.

And I don't think you can avoid circular importing the way you describe it, if every class depends on each other

Comment: I have to disagree. "One class per file" is a very Java-esque mindset, and it's idiomatic for that language, but in Python classes and modules are distinct concepts, and there's no reason to automatically couple them.

Comment: [Python is not Java.](https://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)  Silvio didn't downvote,  which is understandable as he has a "competing" answer, but this is not the way to go.

Comment: as a newcomer, pls pardon the downvote, but it's also important not to lead other people in the wrong direction with such a broad generalization that does not apply to Python in particular.  welcome aboard.